# Is it possible to include request parameter in Fiddler's auto responder feature?

Tags: fiddler, auto-responder

I have two post requests to the same URL and the post parameter is different. Is it possible to use the post request parameter to differentiate those to requests and auto respond them (the URL is the same)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `URLWithBody` match condition:

```
URLWithBody:MatchUrl.php TextToFindInBody
```